# jQuery storing and referring to an array of items

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm not exactly what I'm looking for in jQuery/Javascript terms. The behavior I'm looking for is akin to your typical lightbox slide show with the following elements:

- a list of items
- clicking on an item will bring up a new element that references the item in the list
- while the new element includes next/prev navigation that refers back to the list of items.

I'm building something like that and am looking for the technical approach for handling the above.

I have this for sample code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="samplelink.html">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="anotherlink.html">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="onemorelink.html">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have things set up so that each LI A gets a click event that creates a new overlay DIV on the page, then does a .load($(this).attr('href)) into it.

All that works great.

What I don't know how to do is, pass which index of LI I clicked on to the new div so I can add the proper prev/next links and actually refer to the next/prev element in the original list. Specific example, if I click on the second list item, in the new DIV I create, how do I pass into it the information that "it was the second link that opened this".

Answer (score 1):

In your div code you can select your item again matching on passed href value and use next() and prev() to get the other siblings for given element.

Comment: how should I get the href value into the div to match against it? I suppose I could pass it to a hidden link each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="1">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3">item 3</a></li>
</ul>

<a id="next">next</a>
<a id="prev">prev</a>

<script>
$('ul').bind('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.is('a')) {
      return;
    }
    var li = target.parent();
    console.log('opening: '+target.attr('href'));

    var next = li.is(':last-child') ? li.siblings(':first') : li.next();
    var prev = li.is(':first-child') ? li.siblings(':last') : li.prev();

    $('#next').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
        next.children('a').trigger('click');
    })
    $('#prev').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
        prev.children('a').trigger('click');
    })
    e.preventDefault();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `div` use the jQuery `data` feature to basically "link" the two DOM elements:

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    $("<div class='overlay'></div>")
        .data('trigger', $this)
        .appendTo(body)
        .load($this.attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Then you can just use a `.live` event to capture clicks for `next` and `previous` in your overlay `divs`:

```
$("div.overlay a.next").live('click', function(e){
   var $div     = $(this).closest('div.overlay'),
       $trigger = $div.data('trigger'),
       $next    = $trigger.parent().next();

   if($next.length){
      // It got the next li
      // $next.find('a') would select the link

   } else {
      // It reached the end
      $next = $("ul li:first"); // Grab first now
      // $next.find('a') would select the link
   }
});
```

Write pretty much the opposite for `prev`.